# Wso2 Products executing as windows Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 ESB, DSS and MB. now I am trying to install these products as windows Service by using below URL
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service
I am able to successfully install those 3 products as windows Service. but when I start those services, only first one is starting and the other services getting  error **"The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion." & "A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the WSO2 CarbonDSS service to connect."**

if I start ESB first, I am able to start the service. but DSS not able to start. getting the above error. 
The other way, if I start DSS first, I am able to start the service. but ESB not able to start. getting the above error.

Can you please assist?

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to run multiple wso2 products as windows service now. Actually we have to set unique port or each instance of wso2 products in wrapper.conf file.

**"wrapper.tray.port = 15002 (Port Number)"**

Thanks,
Vinoth

Answer (score 0):

I use 2 WSO2 ESB installed as a windows service on the same machine.

In wrapper.conf, only those values are different :

- wrapper.ntservice.name=WSO2CARBON_Env1
- wrapper.ntservice.displayname=WSO2CARBON Env1
- wrapper.ntservice.description=Carbon Kernel Env1

Comment: Hi, Just did the same. but getting the same error. I did the below steps. can you please confirm is this correct? 1. created two directories. 2. copied wso2esb-4.8.1 & yajsw-stable-11.03 folders to each of the folder. 3. change the offset value "1", & "2". 4. created two environment variable "ESB_HOME" and "ESBB_HOME". set the corresponding path. 5. updated the Service name as mentioned above in wrapper.conf. 6 run the Installservice.bat. 7. I started the first esb instance. sucessfully started. 8. started second one. getting error. Can you please advise i have done some thing wrong?